# getting previously typed commands in python

Tags: shell, command, python-idle, python-2.5

I'm using python 2.5 in windows on a macbook pro with IDLE. How do I get previously typed commands in the python shell? In other operating systems I've managed to do this using 'ctrl' + 'up arrow' or a similar combination. I've tried all likely combinations without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I can find this out in 'Options -> Configure IDLE -> Keys'

It's 'alt + p' for IDLE. Thanks for the suggestion pfote - I will take a look.

Comment: Alt+p is the default; you can bind any key (or key combination) you like in the "keys" configuration pane. Also, repeatedly pressing Alt+p will go further back in the command history; Alt+n can then be used to go forward.

Answer (score 0):

check if there is `ipython` available on windows .. that offers line history, tab completion and many other nice features